# React-Native Fetch + parse JSON crawls in iOS Simulator, but instant in remote Debugging

Tags: ios, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm running a react native app, v56. In the main constructor of the root-level component, I make a fetch() call to a local server, like so:

```
  getStatus = () => {

    let url = this.getEnvUrl();

    return fetch(url)
      .then(res => (_.get(res, 'status', 500) == 200)
        ? res : Promise.reject('Fetch had a non-200 response.'))
      .then(res => res.json() )
      .catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
  }
```

When I run this in the iOS Simulator, res.json() hangs for 10-15 minutes (or longer) before resolving. My machine starts to "lift off" as it begins blowing through my Macbook's resources.

Instead, if I turn on remote debugging, it runs response.json() almost instantly. If I run response.text() instead, it is also immediate.

I am wondering if this is an issue with the simulator, and by enabling remote debugging, the JS is actually running in the browser, and thus more efficiently, or with more resources? My API's json is relatively nested, but I am not having issues with it running on PRODUCTION, with either Chrome, or inside Safari on my iPhone, with much larger requests.

When I looked around, I saw older issues where enabling remote debugging caused a performance hit with .json(), but my issue is the opposite: When I don't have remote debugging on, it eats up my machine, and churns for what feels like a half hour before resolving.

My versions are:
- React 16.3.1
- React Native: 0.55.4
- Node: 9.1.0

Does anyone have any idea here?

Comment: Aside from the code posted above, are there many console.log entries?  Sometimes iOS can get bogged down by them.

Comment: @stever That was it! I wasn't even logging many things, but moving them all to a custom logging module and away from console.log did the trick. Cheers. Add this as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Nice. It’s satisfying to realize that, right?

Comment: Thanks Atomox.  Added it as an answer.

Comment: 100%. I was debugging this for quite some time. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the code posted above, are there many console.log entries? Sometimes iOS can get bogged down by them.

Comment: This was 100% it. Despite only have a few, I was dumping the JSON response. My Macbook was running overdrive, the battery would drain rapidly, and it would take 15-30 minutes for the page to render. Once I removed these, it was resolved instantly.